# Autocomplete JQuery 1.9.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocompletar

Tenho uma aplicação usando *JQuery 1.9.1* (usa a versão antiga porque tem funções no menu que só funcionam nessa versão), estou tentando fazer o autocomplete, mas está dando erro

> ```
> $(...).autocomplete is not a function
> ```

Alguém sabe me dizer se essa versão do *JQuery* tem essa função ou eu que estou errando alguma coisa no código?

**Segue meu código:**

```
<input class="form-control form-control-sm" id="cidadesParadas" type="text"/>

//função para pegar os municipios do controller ListaMunicipios()
var municipios = new Array();

window.onload = function listaMunicipios() {
    var url = "@Url.Action("ListaMunicipios", "Municipio")";

    $.post(url, function (data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            municipios.push(data[i].DescMunicipio);
        }
    });
}

// Chama o Auto complete do JQuery setando o id do input, array com os dados e o mínimo de caracteres para disparar o AutoComplete
$('#cidadesParadas').autocomplete({ source: municipios, minLength: 3 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

acredito que voce esqueceu de colocar `jquery-ui.js`

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: É isso mesmo HudsonPH. Não sabia que tinha que referenciar jquery-ui.js. Achei que a função já estava no JQuery. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

O *plugin* autocomplete, segundo a  [API jQuery](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/), foi incluído na versão **1.8**

Ele faz parte da **jQuery UI**, se carregou o js *jquery-ui.js* tem de funcionar, se não tiver no seu projeto, pode baixar o **jQuery UI** aqui: http://ui.jquery.com/